# Sql on duplicate key update doesn't work

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mysqli

I'm trying to insert a new row (ip) when new computer visits page, but if the key(ip) already exists, I want to update the visit counter ONLY.

Code: `mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO ip_address(ip, ip_count) VALUES (INET_ATON('$ip'),1) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE ip_count = ip_count+1");`

result after 4 refreshes:

[image: result]

Comment: And `ip` is a primary key?

Comment: I suspect that `ip` is primary key.

Comment: The query is correct, but `ip` is not a unique key. To achieve what you want you need to set `ip` as a primary key or unique index.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

You should perhaps use the PHP to validate if it already exists

This is just an example, please use injection-safe methods, and apologies for syntax errors, just trying to show the "logic" here

```
$ip = '' // the way you save the IP address can be put here

$exists = "SELECT * FROM ip_address WHERE`ip` = '" . $ip . "'";
if(mysql_num_rows($exists) == 0) 
    {
      $insert = "INSERT INTO ip_address(ip, ip_count) VALUES (INET_ATON('".$ip."'),1)";
      $mysql_query($insert);
    } 
else 
    {
     while($result = mysql_fetch_assoc($exists))
      {
        $newCount = max($result['ip_count']) + 1;
        $update = "UPDATE ip_address SET ip_count = " . $newCount . " WHERE ip = '" . $ip . "'";
      }
}
```

Basically it selects the data by the IP supplied. If it won't find any, it inserts a new record. If it does, it gets the max ip_count value and updates it with +1.

Again, this most likely won't work with copy & paste, you have to adjust it to your script.

Comment: -1 This is not atomic, it will result in data corruption when concurrent updates are done, either duplicate rows or wrong counts

Answer (score -3):

```
   $ipaddr=<YOUR IP ADDRESS>;
   $sql="update ip_address set ip_count=ip_count+1 where ip_address='".$ipaddr."'";
   mysqli_query($con,$sql);
```

Hope it will work.